# Cardinality of maximal value in a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

Let $\aleph$ stand for the cardinality $|\mathbb R|$ of the continuum, also denoted $\mathfrak c$.

> Let $G = \left \{ S \subset \mathbb{R}: \forall a \neq b \in S, \frac{a+b}{2} \notin S \right \}$
>
> Show that a maximal $S \in G$ exists, and that $|S| = \aleph$.

We can show using Zorn's lemma that there is a maximum, but I'm not sure how to show $|S| = \aleph$.

I guess we should assume it is not $\aleph$, and then show we can choose some $p \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $p \notin S$ and $S \cup \left \{ p \right \} \in G$, but I can't find how to do it.

Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is this question coming from? And what is the context of it?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net University discrete math course. The context is mostly Zorn's lemma and order theory

Comment: Suppose you have $S \in G$ with $\aleph_0 \leqslant \lvert S\rvert < \aleph$. Think about which points $p\notin S$ lead to $S \cup \{p\} \notin G$, and count those points (or find an upper bound for their number). You'll find there are fewer than $\aleph$ "forbidden" points.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! I think I got it.

Comment: @hardmath $\aleph = \mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ is used in some places. In context, it's almost certain this is the case here.

Comment: @paxtibimarce I allowed myself to add a sentence in the question stating that *$\aleph$ stands for the continuum cardinal $\mathfrak c$.*

Comment: @DanielFischer I haven't seen that before... This can be misleading!